# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm implementing an Anguar Interceptor so that any request which comes back from the server with a 401 error should be navigated back to the login page and I'm receiving this error.

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Why am I getting this error?

```
import { Injectable, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

      handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse){
        console.log("Error Occured")
        if(error.status == 401){
          console.log("Error Occured 401")        
          this.router.navigate([""]);
        console.log("Logged Out: Session Timeout")
        }
        return throwError(error)
      }

      intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
      Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
        return next.handle(req)
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError)
        );
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                this.authenticationService.logout();
                location.reload(true);
            }            
            const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
            return throwError(error);
        }))
      }
     }
```

and in service AuthenticationService create method to redirect login

Comment: I tried your code and replaced the Authentication service with           this.router.navigate([""]);
and it redirects to the login page temporarily but again reloads the page I was on after log in

Comment: Okay I removed the location.reload(true) and now it stays on the login page. Thanks for your help it's now working. Although I'm still looking for the reason for the error in my code. Why is it unable to get the navigate method.

Comment: @AviralGoyal pls +1